# Dockerfile - COPY destination filename or directory?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

`COPY` supports two types of destinations: file and directory. In the event that a single file is to be copied into a layer, I've seen cases where the destination is `./` and cases where the destination is just the filename again.

Assuming that there is no intent to change the filename, is a layer that states `COPY filename.txt filename.txt` the same as one that states `COPY filename.txt ./`? If they are the same, are there any special considerations to either method?

Comment: From a semantic point of view, both commands should work identically. Technically, container images are created by starting a container with a base image, modifying it and writing its modified state ([buildah (`builda.io`)](https://buildah.io/) makes this process somewhat transparent). So at the end of the day, both methods should generate the same layer.